# Inserting search box using dataset column using CartoDB?

Tags: data, sql, html, search

I have got some problems to add a search box that can runs searching points from a column of my dataset. I've read this article:

[Linking search box to dataset column in Carto?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153917/how-can-i-link-the-search-box-to-a-dataset-column-in-cartodb)

but I'm not able to resolve the problem beacuse I don't know HTML language, so I don't know what I have to insert, ore what I have to change!

Can anyone help me?